# VisualStudio 2012 devenv.exe @ 50% F5 Debug wont start until its finished whatever its doing

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging, devenv

Help appreciated.

I noticed when pressing F5 to start debugging a WPF app that the green play triangle would gray out then after a second go green again as if debug hadn't started. After some investigation I found that devenv.exe was running hot @ ~50% and the debugger wouldn't start until it came to rest at which point myapp.vshost.exe would be created in task manager/processes and would start to debug.

It can take anywhere from 30 - 120 seconds for devenv to finish whatever its doing and I can begin debugging which is driving me mad.

Ive tried disabling all extensions, restarting Visual studio but they didn't work.

Can anyone cast any light on this annoyance.

Comment: Did you enabled the static contract checker?

Comment: No I haven't, I dont have any extensions enabled at the moment while this is happening.

Comment: In the end I reinstalled VS  all Ok, cant be sure what it was

Comment: Even if it's not 100% satisfying, you may answer to your question, in order to let users know the issue is solved.

Comment: @Steve B, yeah I know what you mean, Have added answer for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS2012 reinstalled to resolve issue.

Awful to have to resort to this but I couldn't afford the time to investigate.